# How to count generated lines of code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, code-metrics, csharp-source-generator

I'm working on a project in which the majority of the code is generated. I'm fully aware of what a useless metric SLOC is, but I'd like to brag about how much work and potential human error the code generators are saving as a KPI to dazzle the PHBs.

How can I count generated SLOC? VS Code Metrics doesn't seem to distinguish between hand-written code and code generated by an `IIncrementalGenerator`. Actually, I'm not entirely sure it's counting the generated lines at all. The generated code can't go in a separate project because many of the generated files are `partial` classes with a few bits hand-written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool NDepend to count generated lines of code in Visual Studio. [A free full featured trial available for download here](https://www.ndepend.com/download).

To avoid reporting issues on generated code, the tool has [a system based on `notmycode` code queries](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax#NotMyCode) to match what is generated code.

[Here are default notmycode code queries](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND3003#!) that can be adapted to your own situations. For example by looking at **CQLinq source code** in this link, you can see something like:

```
...
let sourceFilesPathsToDiscard = (
from filePath in asmSourceFilesPaths 
let filePathLower= filePath.ToString().ToLower()
where     
  filePathLower.EndsWithAny(
    ".g.cs",        // Popular pattern to name generated files.
    ".g.vb",
    ".generated.cs",
    ".generated.vb") ||     
  filePathLower.EndsWithAny(
    ".xaml",        // notmycode WPF xaml code
    ".designer.cs", // notmycode C# Windows Forms designer code
    ".designer.vb") // notmycode VB.NET Windows Forms designer code
...
```

Then in *VisualNDepend.exe* (standalone) or in the *Visual Studio NDepend extension* there is a dashboard that displays the number of generated lines of code (in red in the screenshot below)

[image]

*Disclaimer: I work at NDepend*